# Restructuring data and duplicating rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have a problem with restructuring data. For the entire data set, I need to duplicate each row and insert it to the row right after it, such that

```
row 1
duplicate of row 1
row 2
duplicate of row 2
```

and so on and so forth for the entire data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `rep`

```
df1[rep(1:nrow(df1),each=2),,drop=FALSE]
```

Or using `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
expandRows(df1, 2, count.is.col = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1=1:5, Col2=6:10)
```

Comment: You might want to use `seq_len(nrow(df1))` instead of `1:nrow(df1)` in case `df1` has zero rows.

Comment: No need for an "index" column. Use the `count.is.col` argument. When set to `FALSE`, an arbitrary vector can be entered. When a single value is entered, it is replicated for all rows.